# How to relate coefficients found from row echeolon reduced back to vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asks:

Determine if the vector $v$ is a linear combination of the other vectors.

$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}\
, u_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\
, u_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\
$$

From my understanding the question is asking, find coefficients $c_{1}, c_{2}$ such that $c_{1}u_{1} + c_{2}u_{2} = v$

To do this I put the three vectors in augmented matrix form:

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 0 &  1 \\
    1 & 1 &  2 \\
    0 & 1 & 3
  \end{array}\right]
$$

after elementary row operations I get the matrix:

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 2
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Here is where I'm confused, I don't know how that last row $[0, 0, 2]$ interacts with:
 $$u_1+u_2+\ ?\ =v$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 in the last row indicates that the system is inconsistent; $v$ is thus not a linear combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty much done! You just need to understand how to interpret that last row. It says that (using $c_1$ and $c_2$ as the names of the variables we're solving for)
$$0\cdot c_1+0\cdot c_2=2,$$
or equivalently that $0=2$. What values of $c_1$ and $c_2$, if any, satisfy this equation? And therefore, what do we have to say about the outcome of trying to solve this system of equations?

Answer (score 1):

Using elementary row operations does not change linear dependencies between columns. Thus if some linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ equals $v$, say $av_1+bv_2 = v$, then the same relation is true for the columns in the reduced matrix (and vice versa).

In the row reduced matrix we can clearly see that no such relation exists by considering the third row. Therefore no such relation can exist between the original columns either.